Would a cubic light year of ice cream collapse into a black hole?
I was looking in my Wolfram ChatGPT book and I happened upon the question, "How many calories in a cubic light year of ice cream?"  The software used for the book could not answer so I tried with a newer version and got an answer which makes sense.  Then I asked "Would a cubic light year of ice cream collapse into a black hole?"  Depending upon when I ask and some random effects I don't know about, it gives different answers, none conclusive.
This is the type of question I always enjoy giving to students to get them to understand using units and algebra to get answers, useful or not.  Meanwhile, I'm having trouble coming up with my own answers so I was wondering if I could get some help.  Could I get people to look this over and see if I am thinking of this correctly?
First let's come up with an equation for ice cream. The density of ice cream depends upon many factors, mostly the amount of air whipped into it.  To make the numbers come out more evenly, I'll give the density of water, 1000 $\frac{kg}{m^3}$.  This is a bit more dense than ice cream but it's on the right order of magnitude so it will do.  Google informs me that a light year is 9.46e+15 meters so the volume would be:
$V=({9.46(10^{15})})^3$ m^3
or 8.47e+47 m^3
and the mass would be:
$M={8.47(10^{47})}m^3\times{1000} kg/m^3$
M=8.47e+50 kg
The Schwarzschild radius, the radius which a given mass, if compressed below to that dimension will collapse into a black hole, is defined as:
$r_\text{s} = \frac{2 G M}{c^2}$
If we use the mass of ice cream with this formula, we get
$r_\text{s}=\frac{2G{8.47({10}^{50})}}{c^2}$ meters
where

c speed of light in vacuum 300e6 m/s
G gravitational constant 6.67e-11 Nm^2/kg^2

so:
$r_\text{s}=\frac{2(6.67(10^{-11}))(8.47(10^{50}))}{(300(10^6))^2}$
solving:
$r_\text{s}=1.25({10}^{24})$ meters
Meanwhile, the volume of a sphere is:
$V=\frac{4\pi{R}^3}{3}$
using our volume from before:
${8.47(10^{47})}m^3 = \frac{4\pi{R}^3}{3}$
Solving for R, we get:
$R_\text{ly}=(\frac{3(8.47(10^{47}))}{4\pi})^{\frac{1}{3}}$
$R_\text{ly}=5.87(10^{15})$ meters
If I am interpreting this correctly (and if my arithmetic is correct (two big ifs)), the answer to my question is:
is:
$R_\text{ly} < r_{s}$
The two numbers were 5.87e+15 and 1.25e+24  so  . . . .
YES, A cubic light year worth of ice cream WOULD collapse down into a black hole.

What...is the question? As you.seem to have already answered it.

a star  10 times  solar masses (about 2 a0^31 kg) will collapse into black hole, so I guess your numbers are about right

Sounds like a great submission to Randall Monroe for What If?

@Triatticus Whenever somebody asks a question without any details, the answer is always "show us what you have."  This is what I have, having worked the equations and numbers 15 times.  I think I have it right so I'm asking "Does this look right to you?" Check out the answer from Señor_O where he shows me that I'm making it waaaay too complicated.

See https://www.vttoth.com/CMS/physics-notes/311-hawking-radiation-calculator

Yes that's true, but usually a question title is then explained in the body as to why you asked the question and what issues you have with it....not a calculation performed without reinforcement on why you asked. Though I also second RC_23s comment.

You're obscuring the obvious through a lot of math/calculations.
The mass of a cube is $\rho a^3$ where $a$ is the side length in meters.
The schwarzchild radius of a cube is therefore
$ r_s = \frac{2G\rho a^3}{c^2}$
If you want to set $r_s = a$ you get
$ a = \sqrt{\frac{c^2}{2G\rho}}$
So you can easily calculate the side length necessary for any material given its density. The schwarzchild radius will scale with the cube of the side length.
A cubic light year of ice cream (or any material) is really heavy. It will collapse under its own weight into a black hole, just like a dead star would.

Does it even need to collapse? I think, if we imagine a cubic light year of ice cream, it is a black hole already at $t=0$, since the average density of a black hole decreases as $1/M^2$ with the mass $M$, I remember that the density of supermassive black holes is roughly that of water under normal conditions, and I guess anything that has an average density greater than that of a black hole of the same size is a black hole automatically

good grief. yes, I see.  cubes are not spheres so they don't have a radius but I see where you are going.  This calls for some updated calculations (which I won't enter into SE).

Well if you solve that equation for the density you can see that there needs to be a minimum density for collapse to a black hole.

@DaigakunoBaku “Does it even need to collapse? I think, if we imagine a cubic light year of ice cream, it is a black hole already” - It is not a black hole yet and does need to collapse. All these calculations based on the flat space geometry are inapplicable to curved spaces. One huge misconception that almost everyone has is the “Schwarzschild radius”. It is the reduced circumference of the sphere, but not the distance to the center. Note that the spatial radial distance from the horizon to the origin is zero meters for any black hole. A light year of any matter is very far from that.

@DaigakunoBaku Also note that all matter of a star collapsed to black hole is outside the horizon. Thus in the view where you measure radius as the reduced circumference, you need to move a light year of matter out using linear frame dragging. A black hole is always a result of the gravitational collapse and cannot be  created by just positioning matter in space, no matter how much. This is a popular misconception based on a misunderstanding of curved spaces. A light year of water would break up and collapse into multiple stars to become a violently active region before the final collapse.

@user1683793 that's true, i was assuming since we're dealing with light years of ice cream i could afford to take a little approximation =)
